# strange click behaviour in ios safari

Tags: javascript, html, ios, dom, cordova

i have a strange ios safari issue - i can reproduce the problem in phonegap and the ios browser too:

when you click outside the area of an A tag is has the same effect as actually clicking the tag.

it does not matter if the tag has just an HREF or a click handler.

you can find the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/ygaeb0r5/

also below.

```
<style>
* {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
a {
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: green;
}
img {
    border: none;
}
span {
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 6px;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>

    <title>Template App</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>top
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

    <span>click here</span>
    </div>
    <a></a>
    <a id="a" href="#/chat/name-0">
        name 0&nbsp;<br>description 0
    </a>
    <br />
    <a id="b" href="#/chat/name-1">
        name 1&nbsp;<br>description 1
    </a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var a = document.getElementById("a");
        a.addEventListener("click", function() { alert("a clicked"); });

        var b = document.getElementById("b");
        b.addEventListener("click", function() { alert("b clicked"); });
    </script>
</body>
```

i have also attached a screen shot where i marked in blue the approximative area which when clicked triggers the click for #a or #b - it even includes the bottom half of "click here".

i can also reproduce is on the actual device, but it is easier in the simulator - since you can click more precise using the mouse.

[image: ios simulator]

Comment: fastclick.js seems to fix (partially) the problem. still, why is this happening? is this some usability feature so that the developers cannot create too small tap areas?

Comment: did nobody experience this?